# What is $f(x)-f(x + 2)$ if $f(x + 1) = x(x + 2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is $f(x)-f(x + 2)$ if $f(x + 1) = x(x + 2)$?

---

I have tired but I just cant seem to get my head around it.

Comment: What have you tried? And I don't think linear-algebra tag is the right one for this question.

Comment: Suppose $f(x+1)=x(x+2)$. Then 
$$
f(a+1)=a(a+2), \quad f(b+1)=b(b+2),\cdots
$$
What do you get if you let $a=x-1$, $b=x+1$?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint.

You know that $f(x+1) = x(x+2).$

Let's figure out $f(x)$. Since $x$ is one less than $x+1$, every place we see $x$ on the right side, we replace it with $x-1$:

$f((x+1)-1) = f(x) = (x-1)[(x-1)+2] = (x-1)(x+1) = x^2-1.$

To find $f(x+2)$, simply replace with $(x+1)$ instead.

Can you take it from here?

Here's another way of looking at it.

Let's rewrite the equation with $y$ instead of $x$, since it doesn't matter what we call the variable:

$$f(y+1) = y(y+2).$$

All I did above in the first part was substitute $y=x-1$. This gives me $f(x)$ because $f(y+1) = f((x-1)+1) = f(x)$.

To get the other part you need, which is $f(x+2)$, you simply let $y = x+1$ and do the same thing.

Comment: im sorry no, to be honest i like math and my tutor just hit me with these questions and this is a bonus mark question thats like none of the others. and this is my first time asking for help.

Comment: its quiet strange for me of ask but can you give a full solution with working?

Comment: I calculated $f(x)$ in my answer. Try to find $f(x+2)$. Once you do that, subtract the two expressions and you'll have your answer. If you show me some of what you try yourself, and still aren't getting it, then I'll help more.

Comment: I added another way of looking at it in my answer.

Comment: hi thanks john,  i know your really trying to get me thinking before giving out the answer which is commendable and i thank you for that. to be honestly im just stumped in solving this equation

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $f(x+1) = x(x+2)$, then it must be that $f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: im sorry im puzzled, how did you get to (x-1)(x+1)?

Comment: @James Did you see Jack's comments in OP? In this case Dionel substituted $a=x-1$ in $f(a+1)=a(a+2)$. To do that substitution just requires elementary arithmetic.